# Generate automatic logs when entering and exiting functions .net 2.0

Tags: .net-2.0, log4net, c#-2.0, enterprise-library, asp.net-2.0

I am using .net 2.0. I want to generate the logs when the methods are calling (before call and after call) in a particular class. Is it possible in Enterprise Library 2.0 or log4net? or Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would of course be to just add code to each method. I assume that you do not want to do that.

You should be able to accomplish this with the Policy Injection Application Block, introduced in Enterprise Library 3.0 or the Unity Application Block, introduced in Enterprise Library 4.0. I don't think there is anything built into Enterprise Library 2.0 that would be helpful. I have never used log4net, but I doubt that it has any features that would help either.

You could also look into aspect oriented programming tools, like PostSharp.

[Here](http://bryanhiggins.net/2010/07/07/using-method-interception-to-clean-up-logging-clutter/) is an article on how to accomplish this with Unity.

Comment: +1 The real problem to solve is how to elegantly perform any action on entering and exiting a method. In terms of logging Enterprise Library 3.1 provides the `LoggingCallHandler` to automatically log method entry and exit information.  However, whether this is practical in an existing app using PIAB depends on the current design. To be interceptable a class must inherit from MarshalByRefObject or implement an interface (and then only interface methods can be intercepted). As you mention, probably the least obtrusive way would be a compile-time AOP approach such as PostSharp.

Comment: @Tuzo True, I used Unity to intercept methods in the past and I didn't really like how it impacted my design.